# Creating an Android preferences list using fragments and activities

Tags: android, android-activity, android-fragments, android-preferences

I am trying to create a settings menu using preferenceFragments and preferenceActivities. When I select the Settings button I get an error that the app has crashed. I think I may be missing something. Are there any glaring errors? Thanks!!

I am calling it in the main activity here:

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, UserSettings.class);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the UserSettings class:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.PreferenceFragment;

public class UserSettings extends PreferenceActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, 
                new PrefsFragment()).commit();
  }

public static class PrefsFragment extends PreferenceFragment{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.user_settings);
    }
  }
```

}

This is the user_settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Service Settings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="prefService"
        android:summary="Enable Service"
        android:title="Service" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>
 </PreferenceCategory>

<PreferenceCategory android:title="Other Settings" >
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="prefLockScreen"
        android:summary="Enable Notifications"
        android:title="Notify" >
    </CheckBoxPreference>

    <ListPreference
        android:key="prefUpdateFrequency"
        android:title="GPS settings"
        android:summary="Set GPS Power Usage"
        android:entries="@array/updateGPS"
        android:entryValues="@array/updateGPSValues"
        />
     </PreferenceCategory>  

</PreferenceScreen>
```

I also have an array for the values from updateGPSValues in resources.

Comment: "I get an error that the app has crashed" -- see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this

Comment: Have you declared the Activity on your manifest ? Try posting your error log !

Comment: I totally forgot the manifest! thank you.